# Regex to replace all password with ***

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have the following json:

```
Data: {"Account":"d\\adm","Password":"cWExZjEiMTM="},"SqlServer":{"InstanceName":"","MachineName":"MyMachine","Port":null}
```

I would like to use RegExp to replace Password value with ***.

```
cWExZjEiMTM= => ***
```

In my example I'm expecting the following output:

```
Data: {"Account":"d\\adm","Password":"***"},"SqlServer":{"InstanceName":"","MachineName":"MyMachine","Port":null
```

I only have the following solution:

```
string invokeSpec = "\":{\"Account\":\"d\\\\adm\",\"password\":\"cWExZjEiMTM=\"},\"SqlServer\":{\"InstanceName\":\"\",\"MachineName\":\"MyMachine\",\"Port\":null}";
var pattern = "\\\"Password\\\":\\\"(?<pass>[^\\\"]*)\\\"";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(invokeSpec, pattern, "\"Password\":\"***\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 

":{"Account":"d\\adm","Password":"***"},"SqlServer":{"InstanceName":"","MachineName":"MyMachine","Port":null}
```

Comment: Use a JSON parser.  Don't try parsing JSON with regex.

Comment: @Amy I have to log everything before it goes to deserialization module

Comment: I don't understand what exactly is the question. It seems that you already have a working solution. So, what do you expect from a valid answer?

Comment: You can use JObject.Parse to parse it an object. Then you can try to modify it.

Comment: @Dialecticus I'm looking for replacing only password value. And now I'm replacing `"Password":"Value"`. I mean I would like to kick `"Password"` from my replacement literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people said in the comment, if you can, use a JSON parser instead of regular expression. But let's dismiss that, since that's not the question.

You're capturing the wrong part of your input. What you want is a [substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions).

```
string invokeSpec = "\":{\"Account\":\"d\\\\adm\",\"password\":\"cWExZjEiMTM=\"},\"SqlServer\":{\"InstanceName\":\"\",\"MachineName\":\"MyMachine\",\"Port\":null}";
var pattern = "(\\\"password\\\":\\\")[^\\\"]*(\\\")";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(invokeSpec, pattern, "$1***$2", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

As you can see, we're capturing two groups, the parts that the password is between of. So, there are 3 parts to the regular expression:

- `(\\\"password\\\":\\\")` => Part to the left of the password
- `[^\\\"]*` => the password itself (note that in your example, you can replace this with the non-greedy `.*?`)
- `(\\\")` => Part to the right of the password

And we're referencing them with `$1` and `$2` in the replace method, replacing the original password with `***`.

Comment: my password in base64 format so `.*?` does not work

Comment: Why is that @isxaker? `.` matches any character, `*?` matches until the next part of the regex is matched. base64 strings don't contain backslashes, which is the first character of the right part of the pattern.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to use `JObject` to replace the `Password`

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
jObject["Password"] = "*****";
Console.WriteLine(jObject.ToString()); //save this value to log
```

Comment: While this works, and even though it's clearer, it may not fit OP's performance or otherwise contextual requirements. The question asks for a Regex solution, and this is more suitable as a comment pointing towards good practices.

Comment: @Kilazur this is an answer that OP may choose over the actual answer. Krishna answered the question that OP should perhaps have asked.

Comment: @Dialecticus I do agree with the sentiment, but this is still not the question that has been asked. Moreoever, OP did comment that he needed to do it in Regex; perhaps it's actually not the case, but we don't have enough context to tell so, and to get enough context, it may requires a completely new question indeed. Then again, I have no horse in this race, just wanted to point out to SO etiquette.

Answer (score 0):

```
String pass = "abc=gwdgjs, vhhhhycPassword.10.22.33.09.0=hsdfjs,hjghygh=uhh";
        String passKeyStar = "";
        String passKeyStar1 = "";
        String keyValue[] = pass.split(",");
        for(String t : keyValue) {
        //passKeyStar = t;
        if(t.contains("Password")){
        passKeyStar1=t.split("=")[1];
        }
        }
        System.out.println("replace text: "+pass.replaceAll(passKeyStar1, "******"));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).